# Android drawing.xml does not match bitmap size

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a drawing xml with a size that would match my bitmap file. I am getting all sorts of strange results. My drawing file is called `rr.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <corners android:radius="4px" />
    <size android:height="64px" android:width="64px"/>
</shape>
```

The bitmap I am comparing it to is a 64px x 64px bitmap:

[image: three flags]

The layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnList"
        android:src="@drawable/three_flags_route"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnStatus"
        android:src="@drawable/rr"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am expecting the red square to be the same size as the icon with flags. Instead, I get this (cut from the emulator screenshot) :

[image: screenshot]

It is almost 1.5 times as big! Any ideas how should I specify the dimensions in the xml to make them match?

Comment: you should Use dp instead of pixels.

Comment: No, that will only make the square bigger. The screen resolution of my emulator is more than the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):

> Note: The shape scales to the size of the container View proportionate
>   to the dimensions defined here, by default. When you use the shape in
>   an ImageView, you can restrict scaling by setting the
>   android:scaleType to "center".

Comment: Tried that, it does not make any difference. Edited the question.